# Should I provide a URL as a question?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I have asked a question outside Stack Exchange (in other forums). Should I just provide that URL as a question here? I do not want to create duplicate content on the web.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are going to ask a question on a Stack Exchange site, you need to enter the text of the question. You cannot enter a link to another question asked on another site.

The reason is the same for which a link-only answer is not considered an answer: What would happen if the linked page is temporary unavailable because problems with the server, or permanently not available because that page is deleted?
With a question is even worst because nobody would see the question being asked, while with an answer, the question and the other answers would still be useful to future users.

Comment: Though don't be shy to mention and link to your other question after you included your actual question here.

Answer (score 8):

No. If the question is *good* (it qualifies under the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), and you might also consider [this](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)), we want the content here. Stack Exchange is not a link farm, we want users to be able to find solutions as much as possible without having to click all over the internet.

Answer (score 5):

My instinct is a resounding **no**. StackExchange is a standalone site that shouldn't rely on other sites content. What if the link goes down?

A question consisting of only a link is probably going to be closed as low quality, if the quality filter even lets it through. If you want to post here, repost the entire question you have--including all relevant code--so that it doesn't rely on anything else.

Answer (score 0):

No. Most importantly, the text of the question needs to be here so that it can be found by search engines!

Comment: The odds of the other site going down are relatively low. So that's a less important edge case.

Comment: Cases like this make me wonder whether it's better to edit the other answers. I bet that's an FAQ too?

Comment: @Rory, it's unclear to me which if my statements you're replying to. (It's important, it's indeed Better or it's in the FAQ?) BTW, my second comment is referring to my first comment, not to the OP, in case that's unclear to anyone.

Comment: Pinging @RoryAlsop - was unable to from iOS.