# Should I delete a question with many down-votes?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes

Should I delete [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118746/can-i-provide-a-url-as-a-question) with many down-votes? The question is informative, but people are continuously down-voting it, causing me to lose my reputation.

Comment: [Downvotes are working differently on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences), just as a reminder.

Comment: What question? I don't see a down voted question in your history. Or did you mean here on MSO?

Comment: Not sure we need a meta-vote-disclaimer-bot.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118746/can-i-provide-a-url-as-a-question

Comment: I made a minor edit to it. Originally it read like "I'd really like to be able to do this", which has changed more to "Would this be proper?"

Comment: It stands now on -8/+1 so only -6 rep.. really nothing to worry about.

Comment: @ShadowWizard `+1` is mine - not because I agreed but only to compensate for lost rep :) - at OP's current 66 couple of -1's may indeed feel noticeable

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment this was more like an investment than sympathy. I checked OP background and decided that their contribution so far looks worth some rep. I also found that none of their questions so far deserves my "agreement upvote" so I shelled that rep into the only question where it wouldn't make a substantial difference

Comment: I have the same question. I wanted to provide some useful info and joined a new stack to do so and got my head bitten off:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/68744/can-i-cook-food-in-water-faster-in-a-pan-with-the-lid-on-and-or-high-heat   I agree that it depends. What about here?  I could keep trying to improve my Q and A and delete if the scores stay low or delete now or leave it as is. Feel like abandoning the  cooking stack altogether.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot delete your own question when there is an answer that has been up-voted (at least twice, if I correctly recall).

That said, on this site the down-votes have a different meaning. In most of the cases, the down-votes on meta sites mean disagreement with what implied from the question, in your case, that it is a good idea to report a link to a question asked elsewhere instead of rewriting the question on the Stack Exchange site where you wanted to ask it.

Generally speaking, it is preferable to avoid deleting your own questions because, if you delete too much of your questions, you could not be anymore able to ask new questions until you don't gain reputation by answering questions.

Answer (score 5):

It depends.

- If the question was posted in programming site and was downvoted for being low quality or something like this then yes, there's no much point leaving it around.
- If the question was posted in Meta site (like this) then downvotes only mean the community members don't agree with your suggestion: you should not delete it just because of that.

I understand your reputation loss but even -10 votes means "only" -20 reputation which can be amended by meager 2 upvotes on answer you make or 4 upvotes on other question - really not  that hard to achieve.