# Right way to answer a question with just a link

Tags: support, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

I've replied to a question and I think that the suggestion was right, but I got a -1 score.

I think it happened because I replied with a link to MSDN. Is that right?

Answer (score 12):

Your [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8848986/revisions) was:

> you can find something useful in the msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970689.aspx

This is really not what we encourage — and I wonder why this wasn't blocked or flagged as "low quality". If you post an answer, it should really contain more than just a link somewhere else. See:

> #### [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Instead, show some actual code (like you did in your later revision), and try to address the OP's problem. You'll eventually get a few upvotes, so in the end, the -1 score should not matter.

However, if you just have a link (and nothing more to say), you could post it as a comment instead.

Comment: tnx slhck... the problem is that I can't add comments right now :(

Comment: @SalvatoreDiFazio You only need [50 rep to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment), and that's very easy to gain. There are quite a few [unanswered questions](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered), provide good answers to a couple of them and you've solved your problem, with the added bonus of helping a few more people...

Answer (score 3):

You should read this link:  [What is an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer)

Comment: [Won't is a bot!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118825/168428)  I knew it =)

Comment: +1 for answering in the same way the OP answered that got downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar question that's why [I asked in the meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118746/should-i-provide-a-url-as-a-question) and clarified that I can not post a link as question or an answer because that link may go down, so it is better to post same answer here also or at least add minimum required description as answer.